# How to select DOORS attribute by reference attribute : DXL Script

Tags: attributes, ibm-doors

I have database of doors requirements in a module.
There are 2 attribute for each requirement. When I select first attribute value as `A`, then second attribute value `1` should automatically get updated with that reference.

Similarly for `B -> 2`, `C -> 3`

Using a DXL script, how do I get this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make attribute 2 a DXL attribute with the following code:

```
string attr1 = "NAME_OF_ATTRIBUTE_1"
string attr2 = "NAME_OF_ATTRIBUTE_2"

if(obj.attr1 "" == "A") {
    obj.attr2 = 1
} else if(obj.attr1 "" == "B") {
    obj.attr2 = 2
} else if(obj.attr1 "" == "C") {
    obj.attr2 = 3
}
```

Good luck,
Steve